# Converting geoserver cURL to python requests

Tags: python, django, curl, python-requests, geoserver

Using Django with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) , I want to call a rest server that be configured by Geoserver. In [Geoserver docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html), there are some cURLs that can used for communicate with the server.
For example this cURL:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml"
   -d "<workspace><name>acme</name></workspace>"
   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces
```

creates a new workspace.
How can I convert this cURL to python requests? Also I used following code but it was unsuccessful.

```
payload = {'-d':'<workspace><name>acme</name></workspace>'}
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces", auth=('admin', 'geoserver'),
       data=payload,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
r1 = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces", 
    auth=('admin', 'geoserver'), 
    data='<workspace><name>acme</name></workspace>',
    headers=headers)
```